# How to max datetime value with 7 decimal miliseconds?

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I am trying to load a datetime into a json structure, the date time is being stored as max value with 3 decimals at miliseconds, which causes problems when i parse it to the db, as it converts its to that exact date instead to infinity.

How can i set any datetime which has year as 9999 and miliseconds 999 have 7 decimals in miliseconds and all of them being 9..

I tried setting the value to Datetime.MaxValue but that also only returns 3 decimals for milisecondS?

Comment: I'm not at all clear on what it is you're going for, exactly, but `DateTime.MaxValue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff")` produces a value with 7 decimals for the fractional milliseconds. Do note that if you mean SQL Server with "the DB", there are limits on the precision of `DATETIME` that no amount of parsing will overcome; you'd need `DATETIME2` for that.

Comment: Will that return a string or a datetime?

Comment: For now it seems to work when i use seven decimals rater that 3 whoch used by standard.. The database is a postgresql server.

Comment: `ToString` returns a string, as the name kind of implies... The underlying value of `DateTime.MaxValue` has all the precision you need; if a side processing this value truncates it, that's a separate problem.

Comment: 7 decimal places is a tick which is 100ns.  So just get the ticks :            DateTime maxDate = DateTime.MaxValue;
            long ticks = maxDate.Ticks; //100ns

Comment: Is it physically possible to have such "precise" times? Usually we do not want background noise on our data. Also you should check the interval. You are at boundary of capability of a floating point, so you cannot have much precision. And timestamps after 30 December 2021 are possibly wrong by one second or more.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to translate values one by one from App to DB store.
Your DateTime.MaxValue in your app is only a synonym for the indeed information.
Presumably no limit value for a duration.

Though you could store it also as dbNUll in a db column named "EndDate".
If you wanna differ between "user didnt enter a value" and "user entered infinity", where dbNull is already needed, store your infinity e.g. as a simple year 2200 or whatever is never reachable in your context. If your DB allows negative date values, that can also be a trick to store extraordinary values.

If you use a database provider to create your json, add it as your mapping rule.